# How does Amazon Rekognition bill for face detection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I do have a sample registration system where they can upload image and scan it thru Amazon Rekognition.

I can't seem to find the exact answer on their documentation on how the billing works.

Does it charge every time you compare the image or every time you call the API?

Example: Uploaded image compared to 1000 Images. Does this count as 1000? Or only 1?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/faqs/#Billing

Answer (score 1):

From [Amazon Rekognition – frequently asked questions - AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/faqs/#Billing):

> **Q: How does Amazon Rekognition count the number of images processed?**
>
> For APIs that accept images as inputs, Amazon Rekognition counts the actual number of images analyzed as the number of images processed. DetectLabels, DetectModerationLabels, DetectFaces, IndexFaces, RecognizeCelebrities, and SearchFaceByImage belong to this category. For the CompareFaces API, where two images are passed as input, only the source image is counted as a unit of images processed.
>
> For API calls that don’t require an image as an input parameter, Amazon Rekognition counts each API call as one image processed. SearchFaces belongs to this category.
>
> The remaining Amazon Rekognition APIs - ListFaces, DeleteFaces, CreateCollection, DeleteCollection, and ListCollections - do not count towards images processed.

See also: [Amazon Rekognition – Pricing - AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/pricing/)

Comment: "Amazon Rekognition counts the actual number of images analyzed as the number of images processed." Does this mean if you previously saved 1 million images (e.g. in the Face metadata storage) and then do a SearchFaceByImage of 1 new image against those 1 million images you need to pay for 1 million API calls?

Comment: No idea! But based on the above information, only **images** being processed are charged. Previously-processed images are stored as a face description, not an image. Therefore, it sounds like it would only need to process the 'input' image and thus only be charged for one image.

Comment: We have same use case, and we are charged very high. On checking with their support team on call, they told it counts each faces against which face is matched as separate image processed. Which tells me that, for each 1 image when searched against SearchFacebyImage of collection of 1 million faces, will be counted as 1 million images processed and not the single. This is huge cost! I am now in the process of confirming this with their support team on an email as it doesn't match with the pricing calculator on their site.. and will get this reflected on their FAQ if this is the case.

Comment: Based on the above description and the examples on the Rekognition pricing page, it seems to **bill by image, not Face**. Therefore, your example should only charge for one image. Please let us know what you discover!